# Prediction interval from linear model

Tags: r, lm, predict

I have a linear model `c` showing as "list of 12" giving y=3x+75
I then want a prediction for x=23 with a confidence interval of 95% using the "predict"-formula:

```r
predict(c, newdata=data.frame(BMI=23), interval="prediction")
```

This gives me following:

`List of 16 fit, lwr, upr`

> Warning message:
> 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 16 rows

Any tips to make this work?

Comment: At the very least can you show us the results of `print(c)` or `summary(c)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I can reproduce your warning:

```r
dd <- data.frame(BMI=21:32)
dd$y <- rnorm(12, mean=3*dd$BMI+75, sd=1)
c <- lm(dd$y ~ dd$BMI)
pp <- predict(c,newdata=data.frame(BMI=23), interval="prediction")
## Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 12 rows
```

The way to overcome this problem is to explicitly include a `data` argument in your model, e.g.

```r
c <- lm(y ~ BMI, data=dd)
pp <- predict(c,newdata=data.frame(BMI=23), interval="prediction")
##        fit      lwr      upr
## 1 143.5888 141.8718 145.3059
```

The problem with using `dd$y` etc. in the formula is that R doesn't know what it should be substituting `newdata` for.
Not only does the approach with `data=dd` give you the correct answer, it also makes the `lm()` statement easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided your data/reproducible sample in your question. Based on the error message my best guess is that you have more than one variable in your linear regression. Here's an example of fitting a linear regression and making a prediction:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(y = c(0, 7, 3, 0),
                 x = c(7, 4, 1, 5))
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x, df)
predict(lm1, newdata = data.frame(x = 3))
```

Comment: Turns out i had to use another name in the newdata formula. Could not use "$" symbol

Comment: @nebbdyret, see my answer ...